# wordpress sites saved as apps rather than links when using iphone "add to home screen"

Tags: iphone

When using "add to home screen" in ios safari, the wordpress sites I build for my clients are being saved as discreet apps rather than links that open in the browser.  I tap the newly created icon, and the site opens as an app rather than a new tab in mobile safari (my default browser).

This seems to be semi recent behavior.  Maybe in the past 2 years at the most. I've tested a number of sites, and it seems to only happen on the WP sites I've built within the past 2 years max.  Other sites are saved to the home screen as browser links.  Has anyone encountered this before and know how to stop it from happening?

Comment: WordPress wouldn't be responsible for this, it would be something done by your theme or a plugin. Have you started using a different theme in the last 2 years?

Comment: @Jacob Peattie  You set me on the right path.  The answer is below.  Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An online favicon generator that I use included a site.webmanifest file.  In that file I needed to change this...

"display": "standalone"

...to this:

"display": "browser"